# What characters are allowed in kubernetes port and container names?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

What patterns are valid in kubernetes for the names of containers and ports?

I had underscores in the names of ports and containers and got an error. Replacing the underscores with hyphens worked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Container names and port names must conform to the [RFC 1123 definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#section-2) of a DNS label.

Names must be no longer than 63 characters, must start and end with a lowercase letter or number, and may contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens.

Expressed as a regular expression:

```
[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Here's the applicable code in GitHub for [checking container names](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/53a9d106c4aabcd550cc32ae4e8004f32fb0ae7b/pkg/api/validation/validation.go#L280), [checking port names](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/53a9d106c4aabcd550cc32ae4e8004f32fb0ae7b/pkg/api/validation/validation.go#L133), and [defining acceptable names](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/7f2d0c0f710617ef1f5eec4745b23e0d3f360037/pkg/util/validation.go#L26).

Comment: Note: underscores `_` are not supported.

Comment: @BenMathews The links you shared appear to only apply to ConfigMaps and Secrets, neither of which I see mentioned in the answer. But maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just to have a quick reference this answer isn't valid for the port.name validation and why errors are popping up with longer than 15 char names the latest k8s specs: The container[0].port[0].name must be 15 characters or less as seen by the latest [port.name validation code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/1ffc17e329f9ba3dbe840a7f37513eb8ef074740/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L328).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a regular express. It work to port name.
Expressed as a regular expression:

`^(?!^[0-9]*$)^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|-(?!-)){0,14}(?<!-)$)`

Answer (score 0):

See [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#names) to understand the different naming conventions enforced across the app. Depending on the resource, it could be:

- DNS Subdomain Names
- RFC 1123 Label Names
- RFC 1035 Label Names
- Path Segment Names